# RestAssured OAuth1 authentication problem (Twitter v2 API) in Java

Tags: java, rest-assured, scribe, api-authorization

I am trying to make a request to Tweeter with OAuth1 authentication method in Python I manage to do it with requests library but on Java I use Rest assured. Following code does not work, its return Unauthorized :

```
 Response response = given()
            .headers(headerEmpty())
            .auth()
            .oauth(twitterSettings.getApiKey(), twitterSettings.getApiKeySecret(),
                    twitterSettings.getAccessToken(), twitterSettings.getAccessTokenSecret())
            .spec(baseUrl)
            .get("users/me")
            .then()
            .extract().response();
```

I look online and I found I need to use probably Scribejava library but not sure how to combine with Rest Assured I am not lazy but some help.

EDIT:
I add the dependencies for Scribe and still does not work.

```
public static Headers headerEmpty() {
        Header contentType = new Header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Header acceptType = new Header("Accept", "*/*");

        List<Header> headerList = new ArrayList<>();
        headerList.add(contentType);
        headerList.add(acceptType);

        return new Headers(headerList);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is because of the missing header.
Try adding this header to the request above:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

In order to see exactly the headers you are passing you can change your code like this:

```
 Response response = given()
            .log().all()
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .auth()
            .oauth(twitterSettings.getApiKey(), twitterSettings.getApiKeySecret(),
                    twitterSettings.getAccessToken(), twitterSettings.getAccessTokenSecret())
            .spec(baseUrl)
            .get("users/me")
            .then()
            .extract().response();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer actually I add content type json and accept all.I will try with x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Is not working for the Twitter API i need to find another way.

Comment: What is the response?

Answer (score 0):

I came up on similar problem with Rest assured and OAuth1.
I resolved problem in this way:

```
String oauthHeader = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"" + consumerKey + "\", "
                + "oauth_token=\"" + accessToken + "\", "
                + "oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", "
                + "oauth_signature=\"" + consumerSecret + "%26" + accessTokenSecret + "\"";

    given()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .header("Authorization", oauthHeader)
            .body("xyz")
            .when()
            .get("https://xyz")
            .getBody()
            .prettyPrint();
```

I had a problem to set PLAINTEXT as signature_method.